# Having trouble using a boolean as a filter in django

Tags: django, postgresql

I recently migrated a django project from mysql to postgresql and in the process broke a filter that was being used. The old filter looked like this:

```
return (model_class.objects.filter(status='0',ir=1).count() * 2) +
model_class.objects.filter(status='1',ir=1).count()
```

However, that now produces an error that states:

```
 DatabaseError at /report/trip/publication
 operator does not exist: integer = boolean
 LINE 1: ...AND "publication"."ir" = true )
                               ^
 HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). 
 You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

I've tried setting ir = '1', and I've even tried setting it to '3' (why the hell not?), but regardless of what I set it to, it keeps throwing the same error message, which seems to imply that something else is gunking it up. I did set it to "return None" and that gave me an unfiltered list. The only possible conflict I could see is that there is a declaration up top, but it shouldn't be an issue (it wasn't before):

```
 class Publication(Unit):  
    ir = models.BooleanField(default=False,null=False,verbose_name="Is IR")
```

My postgres database has these fields with the following datatypes:

```
 status  | character varying
 ir      | integer
```

Needless to say, I am extremely confused. I didn't set this up - I'm only trying to fix it (and learn something in the process). What is the proper way to filter this? Any feedback would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Postgres, a BooleanField is of type "boolean".

Quick fix is to change the column in Postgres.